# calculating the latency of parallel asynchronous requests

Tags: c#

I'm using `HttpClient` to perform async requests
The purpose of the script is to send a couple of requests concurrently at one time and display the delay
My Code:

```cs
HttpRequestMessage GetRequest() => new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, SomeURI) {...}  // there I provided empty json content 

async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpClient client)
{
    var before = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var after = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Console.WriteLine((after - before).ToString("G"));  // Console.WriteLine is blocking but I already have the solution
}


var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(_ => SendRequest(GetRequest(), someClient);
await Task.Delay(...);  // Some significant delay
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

But for some reason requests get performed before the task delay, that is the problem, why?

Edit:

```cs
HttpRequestMessage GetRequest() => new (HttpMethod.Put, ApiEndpoints.ChangeName + config.Nickname) {Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.Default, "application/json")};

async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpClient client)
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var after = DateTime.UtcNow;

    var (sent, received, difference) = (now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"), after.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fffffff"), (after - now).ToString("G"));
    var message = new object[] {"status code: ", Color.White, (int) response.StatusCode, " sent at: ", Color.White, sent, " | received at: ", Color.White, received, " | difference: ", Color.White, difference};

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) logger.Success(message);
    else logger.Failure(message);
    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    return response;
}

List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> GetLayer(Account account, int count = 2) => Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(_ => SendRequest(GetRequest(), account.Client)).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Collecting requests");
var layers = new List<List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>> {GetLayer(available[0]), GetLayer(available[0])};
await Task.Delay(...);

foreach(var tasks in layers)
{
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    results.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine((int)r.StatusCode)
}
```

But I'm getting messages before `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: They don't. `tasks` is an enumerable, it is not executed until you enumerate it with `Task.WhenAll`. If that `tasks` line actually ends with `.ToList()` (which it may be given that the trailing `)` is missing), then yes, the tasks *start* before the delay is *awaited*.

Comment: @GSerg thanks, it works, spent 2 hours to it, posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.ToList()` caused tasks to perform, changed it to `IEnumerable<Task<...>>` and it worked, thanks to @GSerg